# Scan all values in sheet1 column b and where each value found on sheet 2 insert value next to each value matched?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to create a script which will run every time I open my workbook, I have several rows of data and in cells D, E & H of each row I have unique values which collectively for each row make a file directory.

```
               Cell D:      Cell E:    Cell H:
Row 1          Folder1      A          1
Row 2          Folder2      B          2
Row 3          Folder3      C          3
```

Row 1's file directory for instance would be:

```
"C:\" & Range("D1").Value & "\" & Range("E1").Value & "\" Range("H1").Value & "\"
```

So translated this would be

```
C:\Folder1\A\1\
```

Inside each directory will be a text file with the same name as the value in column H for each row, for instance:

```
C:\Folder1\A\1\1.txt
```

I want my code to scan each individual folder directory for each of my rows on sheet1 and check if the text file name value exists in column b on sheet2.

i.e. my text file 1.txt (minus the file extension) so filename = 1

sheet 2, column b

1 < Matches the file name from row 1's directory on sheet 1

Then in one cell to the right from the cell where the value was found I want to insert a value "test"

For instance:

```
Sheet 1 column E values:

1.txt 'Minus extension

Sheet 2 column b values

Column B         Column C

1 'Next Cell >'  Test
2 'Value not found so ignored
5 'Value not found so ignored
```

At the moment the code works slightly but only checks one value for the active cell row, and only inserts one value for the single matching value. Is there a way I can get this to check all text files for my rows different folder directories and insert values next to each matching value found?

Code:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
Dim rw As Long, cell As Range
rw = ActiveCell.Row
    With Worksheets("Time Allocation").Columns("B:B")
        Set cell = .Find(What:=Sheets("Home").Range("AB" & rw).Value, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                        LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
        If Not cell Is Nothing Then
            cell.Offset(1, 2) = "Test"  '<~~the default property is the .Value
        Else
            MsgBox "Oooops there was an Error linking Tender reference to Time Allocation Chart."
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Please can someone show me how to adjust my code to get it to do what I need? Thanks in advance